# Standalone F# installer

Tags: f#, installation

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answers help me in any sort.

I would like to know a way of installing F# on a computer that has no internet connection (visual studio is already installed on the target computer, but only C# components). Do you know if it's doable ?
Thanks!

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToMakeAnOfflineInstallerForVS2017.aspx might help. You'd probably want the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp` component, and maybe also the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.Desktop` component.

Comment: Could work, I'll give it a try, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to support .NET Core, then you get everything F#-related just be requiring .NET Core with your Visual Studio installation. This includes the compiler, FSI, and templates. The only thing you'll have missing is the old-style F# templates that don't use the .NET SDK.

Comment: The computer where VS is installed has no internet connection, so I am not able to require the .NET Core.

Comment: When doing an offline installation, you can select any of the components to install, including .NET Core. So this will get you F# support.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you think to this kind of offline installation procedure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019, I am not able to run anything on the connected computer, the only way would be to download a standalone offline installation.

Comment: @EasyHax - It sounds like your setup is a little unusual. Could you describe it more fully? E.g., why are you not able to run anything on the computer that *does* have an Internet connection? And are there any other computers you have access to, maybe at home, where you can both run things *and* have Internet? Maybe you could prepare an installer on one of those computers, then bring it to work on a USB drive. (If USB drives aren't allowed on your non-networked computer, then you'll need to give us more details about how you'd expect to put files on there.)

Comment: The connected computer is running under ubuntu without wine and i am not the SU. By the way I have intalled F# tools but it does not include the template in VS.